# Does TMap::Emplace() overwrite when existing key is applied?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I read Map for STL [does not allow to overwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) value of existing key by emplace() or insert()

However, it LOOKS like Emplace() of UE4 TMap allows to overwrite when existing key with different value is applied.

Am I understanding correctly, or overwriting should not be happened in TMap, too?

Comment: Did you read the [TMap documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/TMap/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Unreal Engine's `TMap` is not equivalent to C++'s `map`. You've already figured it out, but the `Emplace` method in the `TMap` class does differ from C++'s `emplace` method in the `map` class in that calling `Emplace` with a key that already exists in the map will replace the original value associated with that key.

For the `TMap` class, the purpose of the `Emplace` method is to avoid creating copies of non primitive types for the key and value to be inserted into the map. Note that `Emplace` only works on keys and values of an object type that has a single argument constructor. Otherwise, the `Emplace` method behaves similarly to the `Add` method.